# What software is being used in this image recognition system?

Tags: classification

I was wondering if anyone knew which piece of software is being used in this video? It is an image recognition system that makes the training process very simple.

http://www.ted.com/talks/jeremy_howard_the_wonderful_and_terrifying_implications_of_computers_that_can_learn#t-775098

The example is with car images, though the video should start at the right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the software you're referring to is a some kind of **internal** *research project* software, developed by Enlitic (http://www.enlitic.com), where Jeremy Howard works as a founder and CEO. By "internal research project software" I mean either a *proof-of-concept* software, or a *prototype* software.